# SQL Reporting - No report servers were found

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to configure the SQL Reporting Services (local 2016 installation) but get this exception when I open the configuration manager and enter my host name:

[image]

I have installed the services and they run:

[image]

I also checked WBEMTEST and got the instance (with `RS_` in front and `_` coded as `_5f`, which is exactly what I would expect):

[image]

I can connect to it via SSMS:

[image]

I already checked SO and Google, made sure TCP/IP is enabled, tried to repair the SQL Server... I have no more ideas and would be very thankful if someone has already solved a similar issue.

**UPDATE**

I uninstalled the reporting services and installed them again. Now I am not able to connect to the services via SSMS. And still not able to configure them...

Comment: In your first image, what data did you include?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I entered my PC name (after checking that it is the host name in the service properties) and pressed Find. There is no data to include/exclude there.

Comment: Can you connect to the Report Server in SSMS?

Comment: Yes, I can, I will add a screenshot to the description above

Comment: Do you have two versions of SQL Server installed on your machine?

Comment: I have at least three, I think. Could this have any impact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two days spent on this, deinstallation of everything possible incl. all other SQL Server versions, multiple restarts, and so on, I finally found a solution!

I checked all folders

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\xxxx\Tools\Binn
```

for RSConfigTool.exe and started (despite deinstalls and only one result in the search / start menu!) multiple configuration managers until I found this one:

[image]

Here I was finally able to configure the reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution based on hints above. Search for different versions. In my case the exe with the newest file date worked.

[image]